# Wordpress - automatically add to category based on custom field

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-fields

I'm already doing some stuff in the front using a custom field, I'd like to automatically add the post to a specific category if the custom field is ticked.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Regards,

Pete

Answer (score 0):

That should be very easy - just skim the [Wordpress Function Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/).

- You will need to add an [`save_post` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) in your functions.php
- There you will add an simple if-condition for your field (when it is set)
- Then add the post to your category with [wp_set_post_categories](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_categories)

Btw: I think the right plattfrom for this type of question would be https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/